# How can I stop gdb from reading ".cshrc"?

Tags: debugging, gdb, environment-variables, environment

I am trying to debug an application using the gdb debugger.  This application has some specific environment requirements.  Before starting gdb I set up the environment the way I want, then I open gdb.

At first glance it looks like all is well. The command `show environment` shows all of the variables that I want, but when I use the `run` command they magically get reset!

I did some digging and found out that gdb is automatically calling the `.cshrc` file and reloading all of the environment variables, but there doesn't seem to be any way to stop it! How can I stop this from happening?

Is there a way to check inside of the `.cshrc` file if it is being called from gdb and skip it?  I've been struggling with this for days and it's incredibly irritating.

Comment: You are mistaken: GDB doesn't read your `~/.cshrc` -- your `$SHELL` does. And preventing your shell from mucking with environment when it is running non-interactively is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found one solution, but I'm not sure if this is going to break other things on the server yet.

I added the following code the the `.cshrc` file and now it aborts when it is called by gdb:

```
if ( ! $?prompt ) then
    exit
endif
```

This code basically tells it to abort if it is being called by something other than an interactive shell.  It works for now, but I have a feeling that I may find out this breaks something else in the future.